# HTML TO WP Theme : Submenu goes down wp_nav_menu

Tags: theme-development, customization, menus

I have to convert a html to wp but there is an issue sub menu is not working properly.I am newbie but I have done something for that still not success.

**header.php Code**

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">WpF <span>BGness</span></a>
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a> -->
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar_area">          
       <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom_nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>               
            </ul>
          </li>             
          <li><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog-archive.html">Blog</a></li>                    
        </ul> -->


         <?php 
     $params = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class' =>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
        );
    wp_nav_menu($params);
            ?>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**functions.php**

```
function at_theme_setup()
{
    //Register Menu

    register_nav_menu(
        'primary',__('Primary Menu')
        );

}
add_action('after_setup_theme','at_theme_setup');
```

**Current output**

[image: submenu not working in html its proper]

Comment: I don't think it's a WordPress problem. You just need to concentrate on CSS.

Comment: Its working in html.

Comment: <ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://localhost:8080/developplugin/gallery-page/">Gallery Page</a></li>
</ul>